# Android how to add support of unsupported media formats

Tags: android, media

How can I add suport of these audio formats to Adnroid application:

- AA
- Dolby Digital (AC3)
- AAC
- ADX
- ASF
- AHX
- AIFF
- APE
- AUD

and many others. Is it real? Or is it too hard to implement?
The same question is related with video, text files (djvu, pdf etc) and playlists (B4S, FPL).

Thank you.

Comment: You either find a library or implement your own handler for such formats. You are cordially invited to use a search engine to do such research.

Comment: I found https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg but it is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Vitamio](http://www.vitamio.org/en/). It is an open source library that supports many different media formats. Some of the supported formats are listed [here](http://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/Basic/2013/0509/4.html).